# Impact of using extern "C" { on C++ code when using g++

Tags: c++, c, g++, gnu

When using G++ (e.g. version 4.5 on Linux) can anyone explain what will/can happen if a user writes a header file for a mixed C/C++ system like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 

extern "C" {

int myCPPfunc(some_arg_list....); /* a C++ function */

}
#endif
```

but here `myCPPfunc()` is a normal C++ function with a class def inside - i.e. it was wrongly labeled as a C function.

What is the impact of this?

Comment: `extern "C"` affects only linkage, it doesn't magically turn C++ compiler into a C compiler. The code is still pure C++.

Comment: linkage? beyond name mangling nothing?

Comment: @PeterToft: technically, it could affect more than name mangling - for example other aspects of the calling convention could be different between C++ and C functions. But since the name mangling forces you to use `extern "C"` to get C++ and C functions interoperable anyway, the other details that may or may not get thrown are academic. I think for nearly all compilers, a `static` or non-member C++ function will have the same calling convention as a C function - that's why passing function pointers for callbacks will usually work between the two languages. But I've heard of exceptions to that.

Answer (score 1):

The main impact of this is that you cannot overload it, e.g. this is legal:

```
int myCPPfunc(int a);
int myCPPfunc(char a);
```

But this is not:

```
extern "C"
{
    int myCPPfunc(int a);
    int myCPPfunc(char a);
}
```

Comment: Pass-by-reference is also a C++-ism that many C++ programmers working in C might not realize immediately.

Comment: Sure Danis example - like mine - is wrong, but what is the impact? The short answers is "it works", but I am not too sure when I add valgrind to the picture....

Comment: I want to reemphasize that what you have is *not necessarily wrong*.  As long as everything from `extern "C" {` to the matching `}` could be processed without error by a C compiler, you're probably fine.  (I say "probably" only because I may have forgotten a subtlety that doesn't matter in real life.)

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly legitimate to have the *implementation* of an `extern "C"` function use arbitrary C++ features.  What you can't do is have its *interface* be something you couldn't do in C, e.g. argument overloading, methods (virtual or otherwise), templates, etc.

Be aware that a lot of the "something you couldn't do in C" cases provoke undefined behavior rather than prompt compile errors.

Comment: I found some code which has worked fine - for years.... Like that, but the code used the extern "C" opposite of the normal meaning: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask me, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This tells the C++ compiler that the functions declared in the header file are C functions.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.2

Comment: yes, but what is the impact of making this wrong. It is at least about function name mangling, but any impact to stack and heap handling?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `extern "C"` is for - it allows you to write a C++ function that can be called from C.

Essentially, that declaration is telling the C++ compiler that you want the C++ function `myCPPfunc()` to have an external interface that is linkable (and therefore callable) from C.

The implementation of the function is still C++ and can still use C++ features.

Typically, the declaration of the function in the header file might look more like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif

int myCPPfunc(some_arg_list....); /* a C++ function */

#ifdef __cplusplus 
}
#endif
```

That lets the same header file be used by either the C++ compiler or the C compiler, and each will see it as declaring a C callable function.

Comment: Are you not turning the bucket around here - e.g. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html They explain it as call C-functions from C++ when using extern "C" { XXX }

Comment: This is an instance of "[32.6] How can I create a C++ function f(int,char,float) that is callable by my C code?" (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.6). The conditionals make the `extern "C"` visible to the C++ compiler, but not the C compiler.  For the function declaration, that's needed if you have a function written in C that needs to be callable by C++ code or the other way around. A C callable function has to be declared `extern "C"` to a C++ compile whether the function is implemented in C or C++.